# What is the difference between dockerd and com.docker.service in Docker for Windows?

Tags: docker, containers, windows

What is the difference between *dockerd* and *com.docker.service* in Docker for Windows? Or rather I should ask: why do I need (if I need) *com.docker.service* running?

**Intention:** I want to use Docker only with command line in Windows environment in Windows container mode, control it with PS scripts etc. etc.

For me the role of *com.docker.service* is unclear.

I am able to run *dockerd* process and pull and run containers, when *com.docker.service* is stopped. When I start it - nothing happens (or maybe I don't notice the change).

Comment: Perhaps the following documentation may provide some clarification: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/permission-requirements/#privileged-helper https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/ https://docs.docker.com/get-started/overview/#docker-architecture

Answer (score 2):

dockerd is a persistent process that manages containers. Docker uses different binaries for the daemon and client. ( from Docker site ). Docker Daemon is a server which interacts with the operating system and performs all kind of services. The Docker Daemon listens for REST API request and performs the operation. Its process running on the background.

Docker service is the utility we use when we run any docker commands e.g. docker run (docker container run), docker images, docker ps etc. It allows us to run these commands which a human can easily understand.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood something, but you don't need _com.docker.service (Docker Desktop Service)_ running to use Docker commands. That puzzles me. I can run just: _Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\dockerd.exe' -Verb RunAs_ and then use _docker pull_ or _docker run_ perfectly fine. It seems to me that _Docker Desktop Service_ main purpose is managing VMs, like MobyLinuxVM when switching to Linux container mode. Also I don't need the service running when I change the isolation mode on Windows containers, just _dockerd_ process. It needs further investigation.

Comment: Can you try stopping the docker service by going to services manager in windows and execute the docker commands? it would be great if you can let me know, if Docker commands are running after stopping the Docker service

Comment: The service is not running, but _dockerd_ process is. I have Docker Desktop GUI disabled. I am able to run Docker commands, pull and run images and switch istolation mode (to _hyperv_ or _process_) in Windows containers mode. The only time I need Docker service running is when I need to switch to Linux container mode.